# Is there a way not to re-send an email to soft bounces?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, deliverability, bounce-management

Is there a way to not re-send an email if it soft bounces during a deployment?

OR even if it bounces once to not to retry them?

I'm not too sure if this is even possible. I know the SFMC automatically retries soft bounced addresses every 15 mins.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can raise a support ticket to have the rules behind bounce mail management adjusted according to your requirements.

As per default, this is how bounces would be treated:

> To turn a subscriber status to *Held*, mail to that address has to
>   have bounced 3+ times with at least 15 days between first bounce and
>   most recent bounce.

The “3 times” and the “15 days” setting can both be modified. Either to less or more restrictive settings.

For each type of bounce you have two options:

- Apply the “X over Y days” logic
- “One and done” - one single bounce turns an address to “Held” status.

The last one is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, the solution described above by Mr. Lunow is unfortunately not valid anymore since "Bounce Management settings customisation" is no longer supported :(

[image]